# How can I use the ArcGIS JavaScript API along with a separate version of Dojo?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript in my application which is being developed using IBM WebSphere Portal.

When I integrate ESRI with my HTML code it works fine but when I load the ArcGIS JavaScript API which also loads Dojo which is heavily used in my application breaks.

My application was developed with Dojo 1.7 but since i am using ArcGIS JavaScript API version 3.6 which loads Dojo 1.8.3 I find there are a few issues. Sometimes things work and sometimes everything fails.

I get `'this.navigationManager' is null or not an object` in IE and Firefox, while on Chrome I get a different issue pointing to `init.js`.

I am not able to figure out what could be the issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the issue to provide an answer but these pages may help you: [The Dojo Loader - Relocating Module Namespaces](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#relocating-module-namespaces), [Multiple Versions of Dojo on a Page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/multiversion.html)

Comment: Can you clarify your second sentence? I am not following you there.

Comment: I get 'undefined' is null or not an object  init.js, line 15 character 94901   whenever i load my portal pages i don't know what could be the issue

Answer (score 1):

changes to Dojo's loader in more recent versions of their API have made loading multiple versions and remapping namespaces substantially more difficult.

we have requested that the Esri JS API dev team put together a sample demonstrating how to do this post Dojo 1.7.x, but for the time being i'd try and avoid remapping the dojo namespace that comes bundled.